# MySQL if statement fails

Tags: mysql

I have a function called tableExists. It can be used to check for the existence of a table. I want to use it in a DB upgrade script. I can use the function like this:

```
select myDb.tableExists('myDb', 'someTable') as cnt into @exists;
```

And see the results like this:

```
mysql> select @exists;
+---------+
| @exists |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
```

Now, I want to use it in an If statement, followed by a create table statement. But, I am having problems with the if. The following is what I am trying to test with:

```
mysql> IF (@exists = 1) THEN
    -> select 'exists'
    -> END IF;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
right syntax to use near 'IF (@exists = 1) THEN
select 'exists'
END IF' at line 1
```

What am I missing here? This should be simple.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?  This seems like spooky black magic to me

Comment: MySQL flow control statements `IF/ELSE/WHILE...` are meant to tbe executed in context of a stored procedure or function, not interactively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use the `IF` inside a stored procedure.

The valid select statement would be:

```
SELECT CASE (@exists) WHEN 1 THEN 'exists' END as DoesItExist
```

If you use the case as a stand alone element in a stored proc, you'll need to end it with `end case` how ever.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `IF NOT EXISTS` in the `CREATE TABLE` query and save yourself all this trouble:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table IF NOT EXISTS
... {table definition}
```

If the table already exists, nothing will happen.